# I want to be able to track swipes without disabling scrolling on the phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, swipe, gesture

I have a swipe functionality on my mobile page, and Im able to track swipes swipes with touchmove but it basically disables the scrolling option in that section of the page.  Is there a way to track swipes and make that area still scrollable.  Here is my code:

```
jQuery('.first-frame').bind('mousedown', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Landing-Page', 'Swipe-Toggle-Color', '0259_2190']);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that's currently disabling the scrolling is the `event.preventDefault();`. This prevents the default action from happening which on a phone would be scrolling. Although I would do this differently. This way you can get the direction of the swipe also(unless there are more swipe options than just left and right).

```
jQuery('.first-frame').on('swipeleft swiperight', function(event) {
    var direction = (event.type === 'swipeleft' ? 'left' : 'right');
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Landing-Page', 'swipe', direction]);
});
```

Comment: Cool thanks that solve part of the problem but if I want to use the following code -- jQuery('.first-frame').bind('mousedown', function(event) {
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Landing-Page', 'Swipe-Toggle-Color', '0259_2190']);
}); -- and prevent to fire the event when scrolling.

Comment: You then want to use `touchstart`, `touchend`, & `touchmove` to do what you're thinking. Just `setTimeout` the `_gaq.push` to a global variable and if the `touchmove` event happens use `clearTimeout` on the global variable so it doesn't run. This way taps still send the push but swipes don't.